# Maximum likelihood estimate for a univariate gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

Say we have a univariate Gaussian distribution $p(x)=\mathcal N(x|\mu, \sigma^{2})$. Then suppose we have a data set of observations $X = \{x_1, x_2, \cdots ,x_N\}^{T}$ that are drawn independently from this distribution.

By performing MLE, which means by maximizing 
$$\ln\prod_{n = 1}^{N} \mathcal N(x_n|\mu, \sigma^{2})$$ with respect to $\mu$ and $\sigma$ respectively, I can get the maximum likelihood solution for $\sigma$, which is 
$$\sigma_{ML} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = 1}^{N}(x_n-\mu_{ML})^{2}$$

Clearly, in front of the summation, we have a $\frac{1}{N}$. However, I also read that the maximum likelihood solution for $\sigma$ is 
$$\sigma_{ML} = \frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{n = 1}^{N}(x_n-\mu_{ML})^{2}$$, in which $N$ still denotes for the size of the dataset.

Why are the two solutions different? How do we have $N-1$ on the denominator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n = 1}^{N}(x_n-\bar x)^{2}$ [is the maximum likelihood estimator](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48671/what-is-restricted-maximum-likelihood-and-when-should-it-be-used/48676#48676), it is biased and using $\frac{1}{N-1}$ instead [corrects this bias](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17890/what-is-the-difference-between-n-and-n-1-in-calculating-population-variance). So the first equation (a.k.a. population variance) is the maximum likelihood estimator, while the second one (a.k.a. sample variance) is the bias-corrected one.